# calling the DOM in a jQuery argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm still learning jQuery and I'm creating a very simple jQuery function that uses an argument and then I call divs in the argument. However it doesn't work. I am not getting any errors in the console. Here is my code:

```
function square(oneDiv) {
    var divWidth = oneDiv.width();
    oneDiv.height(divWidth);
}

square($('.art'));
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If the selector (`'.art'`) does not match anything in the document, then the code will not do anything and there won't be any errors. You can check that by logging `oneDiv.length`.

Comment: What are the errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things could be going wrong.

1) The DOM might not exist by the time this code runs.  For that case, wrap your function call in a `$(document).ready` as so, which will ensure that `.art` will exist when the function runs:

```
function square(oneDiv) {
  var divWidth = oneDiv.width();
  oneDiv.height(divWidth);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  square($('.art'));
});
```

2) The `.art` element might have a `display: inline` style.  Make sure it's either `display: block` or `display: inline-block`.  Height and width styles on inline elements are ignored.

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/o3dqzgno/

Answer (score 0):

try this. Also make sure your query code is loaded after the element with a class='art' element is loaded in the dom

```
function square(oneDiv) {
    var myDiv = $(oneDiv);
    var divWidth = myDiv.css('width');
    myDiv.css('height', divWidth);
}

square('.art');
```

Comment: Why? Passing a jQuery object as an argument to a function, then using its methods is perfectly OK. BTW `.css('width') != .width()`

Comment: For the sake of reusability, would it not be better to change it to take a jQuery object as a parameter rather than just the class/id?

Comment: @natzim, I would argue that the method of 'getting' the element should be up to the method, that way you can refactor the method but have the interface i.e. square(String); the same. For example you might stop using jquery and use mootools(!) you can still use square(String) and refactor only the method

Comment: I'm all for suggesting better alternatives (if explained why it's better), but the code in OP's question is not wrong, so refactoring  doesn't explain why it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @atmd Good point, I guess it depends on what OP wants to use the function for.

Comment: @pawel no your right, there is nothing wrong with passing a jquery object at all, and you also right the .css('width is not equal to .width(), as no calculations are going on I'd suggest .css('width is the better choice. I certainly wasnt intending to suggest that the OP code was bad or anything, just offering an alternative as its not cleasr with out much more information why the code the OP has posted isnt working